# How to only allow capital letters to be input to a variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to write some code which allows a user to input a word, but all the letters in the word have to be capital letters. The message also can't contain spaces or punctuation.

Comment: What code have you tried??

Comment: What should happen if the word contains illegal characters? Remove them or give some feedback to user?

Comment: I'm coding it in python, and if what the user has inputted a message containing illegal characters, there should be a message printed saying the message can only contain capital letters. and ask them for a new input .

Comment: Give us some code that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python strings support `.isupper()` and `.isalpha()` so:

```
>>> def upperalpha(s):
...   return s.isupper() and s.isalpha()
...
>>> upperalpha('ABC')
True
>>> upperalpha('ABc')
False
>>> upperalpha('ABC1')
False
>>> upperalpha('ABC DEF')
False
>>> upperalpha('ABCDEF')
True
>>> upperalpha('ABCDEF!')
False
```

A simple input loop could be:

```
>>> while True:
...   word = input('Enter a word: ')
...   if word.isupper() and word.isalpha():
...     break
...   else:
...     print('Please enter only uppercase letters, no spaces or punctuation.')
...
Enter a word: asdf
Please enter only uppercase letters, no spaces or punctuation.
Enter a word: asdf123
Please enter only uppercase letters, no spaces or punctuation.
Enter a word: 123
Please enter only uppercase letters, no spaces or punctuation.
Enter a word: ABC123
Please enter only uppercase letters, no spaces or punctuation.
Enter a word: ABC 123
Please enter only uppercase letters, no spaces or punctuation.
Enter a word: ABC DEF
Please enter only uppercase letters, no spaces or punctuation.
Enter a word: ABC
>>>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I am completely lost with the definition stuff i would find it easier to comprehend if it was without that... Actually dont worry i changed some stuff about myself and go it working for me but thankyou very much for your help.

Comment: @user5537402, I'll make the change, but get used to it.  Defining functions for repeatable actions is used in all languages and saves repeating a lot of code...as you'll see.

Comment: Ok well i am very new to coding and right now I'm just doing it for fun, but thank you for your advice next thing I'll teach myself will be funtions.

Answer (score 0):

Simple try may be ( for single word not number mixed)-

```
inp = raw_input("F:")

if inp == inp.upper():
    print "Hi"
else:
    print "please enter Upper case word"
```